# How to change mySQL root password in MAMP

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I installed mySQL a while back but have now installed MAMP which also includes mySQL. I want to change the root user password in this new mySQL instance but I can't get this to work:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p --port=8889 --protocol=TCP password myNewPassword
```

(I have to use the port # and TCP protocol, otherwise it just tries to connect to my older mySQL instance)

The error I get is:

> mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
>   Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
>   mysqladmin: unable to change password; error: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() IDENTIFIED BY 'myNewPassword'' at line 1'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also tried logging in and using ALTER USER, but that didn't work either:

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myNewPassword'; ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'myNewPassword'' at line 1

Answer (score 10):

From the MAMP FAQ:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password <NEWPASSWORD>
```

Replace  with the new password. You need to provide the existing root user password (e.g. ‘root’).

Afterwards, you also need to change the password for phpMyAdmin and other scripts which are used with MAMP. You can change the password for phpMyAdmin in the file /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out ALTER USER is for mySQL 5.7.x only; for the mySQL version that comes in MAMP 4.1.1 (v 5.6.35):

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```